# Swift Metal Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED BERT Model

Tags: swift, machine-learning, bert-language-model

I've recently been working on an app where a user can ask questions about a text and the app will print out the answer. For that, I used the Apple [Finding Answers to Questions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/finding_answers_to_questions_in_a_text_document) template, which is powered by BERT. This template worked just fine, until yesterday when it always printed out the error message:

```
Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
```

when executing the BERT inference code:

```
let answer = self.bert.findAnswer(for: searchText, in: detail.body)
```

I haven't changed anything of the code, so this seems like a bug, does anyone know how to solve it or did anyone have similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by cleaning my build folder, therefore this issue seemed to be caused by corrupted cache files.